# Why am I getting ProvisionedThroughputExceededException when writing a large number of records to Kinesis?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I'm using Lambda and Kinesis together, to validate and insert batches of records. I'm new to Kinesis so I'm not even sure what I'm looking for, or if I've misconfigured something. I'm having a very hard time understanding the complexity of Kinesis for what is a simple use-case.

I'm splitting one large file into several smaller ones - say, 275,000 lines in one file into 275, 1000-line files. Once the file is broken up, the files are uploaded to S3 in a matter of about 30 seconds, which triggers the producer lambda, which then writes to Kinesis, which triggers a consumer lambda that writes the records to Postgres in batches of 10.

Everything works great when I test with 100, 1000, or even 20000 records. When I attempt to run all 275,000 records, I start seeing the following types of errors arise when uploading larger data sets:

> ProvisionedThroughputExceededException: Rate exceeded for shard

I end up with around 130,000 of the records, once completed.

Each aforementioned file is under 1MB and contains 1000 JSON records. Each JSON record has 40 fields and doesn't contain much data. These aren't huge records.

From what I can gather, There are too many reads when the consumer is triggered, for what the stream can handle. I guess I need Enhanced Fan-Out?

If I bump up the batch size of the event source, somewhere, somehow, errors are happening...I guess...because I'll get several times the records I expect.

CDK Infra:

**Kinesis**

```js
export class StreamStack extends Stack {
    public readonly myStream: Stream;

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        this.myStream = new Stream(this, "MyStream", {
            streamName: "my-stream",
            streamMode: StreamMode.ON_DEMAND
        });
    }
}
```

**Event Source**

```js
interface EventSourceStackProps extends StackProps {
    myStream: Stream,
    myConsumerLambda: NodejsFunction
}

export class EventSourceStack extends Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: EventSourceStackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        new EventSourceMapping(this, "ConsumerFunctionEvent", {
            target: props.myConsumerLambda,
            batchSize: 10,
            startingPosition: StartingPosition.LATEST,
            eventSourceArn: props.myStream.streamArn
        });
        props.myStream.grantRead(props.myConsumerLambda);
    }
}
```

**Producer and Consumer Lambda functions in a larger `LambdaStack`**

```js
        this.myProducerLambda = new NodejsFunction(this, "MyProducerLambda", {
            functionName: "myProducerHandler",
            runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
            handler: "myProducerHandler",
            entry: "./lambda/myProducerHandler.ts",
            memorySize: 256,
            timeout: Duration.minutes(5)
        });
        props.myStream.grantWrite(this.myProducerLambda);

        this.myConsumerLambda = new NodejsFunction(this, "MyConsumerLambda", {
            functionName: "myConsumerHandler",
            runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
            handler: "myConsumerHandler",
            entry: "./lambda/myConsumerHandler.ts",
            memorySize: 1024,
            timeout: Duration.minutes(15)
        });
```

The **producer** sends records in like so:

```js
export const putStreamRecord = async (item: StreamItem): Promise<void> => {
    try {
        const client = new KinesisClient();
        const params = {
            Data: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(item)),
            PartitionKey: item.key,
            StreamName: process.env.STREAM_NAME,
        };
        await client.send(new PutRecordCommand(params));
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        throw e;
    }
};
```

The **consumer** function looks something like this:

```js
export const myConsumerHandler = async (event: KinesisStreamEvent): Promise<boolean> => {
    let batchSaveRes = false;
    try {
        //extract batch records
        const batchData = event.Records
            .map(rec => Buffer.from(rec.kinesis.data, "base64").toString())
            .map(buff => JSON.parse(buff))
            .map(item => item.payload);
        
        batchSaveRes = await consumeBatchStream(batchData);
        return batchSaveRes;
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("ERROR:", e);
        return batchSaveRes;
    }
};
```

The **consumeBatchStream** reference there, is straightforward. It just batch inserts the data into Postgres.

```js
export const consumeBatchStream = async (batchData: Record<string, unknown>[]): Promise<boolean> => {
    let client: Client | null = null;
    try {
        client = await getDbClient("my-secret");
        await client?.connect();
        const query = //...builds an insert query;
        await client.query(query);
        console.log("INSERTED:", batchData);
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error consuming batch stream:", e)
        throw e;
    } finally {
        await client?.end();
    }
};
```

Would SQS/SNS give me what I need without the limitations I'm hitting with Kinesis? I really just need a simple way to notify multiple consumers about new records of certain types. I don't care about ordering.

I used to do this sort of thing in Kafka without nearly as much trouble, as a developer. Records go in, consumers pick them up, and all works well.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things seemed to help this situation.

First, pushing the batch size on the event consumer to 100 from 10 eliminated the errors on the consumer side. Then, by randomizing the `PartitionKey` on the `PutRecordCommand` on the producer side, ensured all records made it through w/o error:

```js
export const putStreamRecord = async (item: StreamItem): Promise<void> => {
    try {
        const client = new KinesisClient();
        const params = {
            Data: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(item)),
            PartitionKey: uuid(),//item.key,
            StreamName: process.env.STREAM_NAME,
        };
        await client.send(new PutRecordCommand(params));
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        throw e;
    }
};
```

Makes sense...had a "hot partition" and overlooked it.